# Writing to Firebase from GAS returns error

Tags: google-apps-script, firebase, urlfetch

I am trying to write to Firebase from Google Apps Script.

I try this:

```
var act="https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/fred/name.json";
UrlFetchApp.fetch(act,{"method":"post","payload":"test"});
```

and I get this error:

```
Request failed for https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/fred/name.json
returned code 400. Truncated server response:
{ "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value.
Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names." }...
```

### Question

> **How do I write to Firebase from GAS?** (What am I doing wrong?)

Comment: why would this imply that https isnt supported? if so show us the same working with http

Comment: @ZigMandel: You are correct! I reworded the question. Thanks. Upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

> **You must `stringify` the `payload` object.**

[Here is a question and answer example](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/0kgrwV-3ieE/3jnS-v3iZwUJ).

I tested it and it does work.

---

#### Example

```
function putToFire() {
  var payload = '{ "first": "Foo", "last": "Bar" }';
  var options = {
    "method": "put",
    "payload": payload
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/fred/name.json",             
     options
  );
}
```

---

#### The Key Trick

> **Notice the single quotes `'` around the `payload` object?**

In the following line:

```
  var payload = '{ "first": "Foo", "last": "Bar" }';
```

That counterintuitive syntax seems to be the trick to making this work. ;-)

---

#### Alternative Syntax for Variable Payloads

If your `payload` is a variable, you can use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
  var payload=JSON.stringify({"first":"Foo","last":"Bar"});
```